# Change Output for Images in Content

Tags: post-thumbnails, images, content

I want to wrap some html (divs and classes) around the  tag (to create the appearance of photo corners by way of an image sprite).

Basically, I want to re-write all  tags added by WP in the content by way of some code in my functions file from this:

```
<a href="#link"><img src="image.jpg" class="someclass"></a>
```

to this:

```
<div class="featured-img">
    <a rel="#lightbox" href="#link" class="#lightboxclass"><img src="image.jpg" class="someclass"></a>
    <div class="corner-nw"></div>
    <div class="corner-ne"></div>
    <div class="corner-sw"></div>
    <div class="corner-se"></div> 
</div>
```

I want this done *after*  the page has been added/edited by me or anyone else adding content.  I tried using [wp_get_attachment_image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) with the function below, and it added the html ONLY when adding the image the first time into the edit content screen.  Plus, when the image itself is dragged around inside the edit box, or possibly removed, remnants of the html are messed up.

```
    function image_corners( $html, $id, $alt, $title ){
    $html = '<div class="featured-img"><img src="' . esc_attr($img_src) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($alt) . '" title="' . esc_attr($title).'" '.$hwstring.'class="'.$class.'" /><div class="corner-nw"></div><div class="corner-ne"></div><div class="corner-sw"></div><div class="corner-se"></div></div>';
    return $html;
    }
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image','image_corners',10,4);
```

It seems like every option I look at with a filter or a hook only adds it during the add-image step in the edit screen.  Am I mistaken on this?  I'd be fine with a jquery option to change the html on/after page load, but I'm not quite sure how to write that, and not sure if that is necessary?  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not use JS/jQuery? A simple check to see if *img.imgWithCorner* exists, and then a append/prepend function.

Comment: I think the code/images after "from this" and "to this" are missing

Comment: Yes Naoise, so sorry.  Went back to grab the code and then hit the submit button.  I'll go fix the question now.

Comment: cr0z3r, how would that work?

Comment: Well I've solved half of it ... The featured images were easy to change the layout.  Now, to figure out how to get the code set up for the images that WordPress automatically inserts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to do this dynamically:

```
function do_the_replacements($matches){

  // $matches[0] = full string
  // $matches[1] = link attributes
  // $matches[2] = link contentes (the image)

  // change 'someclass' here...
  if(strpos($matches[2], 'someclass') !== false){
    return '
      <div class="featured-img">
        <a '.$matches[1].'>'.$matches[2].'</a>
        <div class="corner-nw"></div>
        <div class="corner-ne"></div>
        <div class="corner-sw"></div>
        <div class="corner-se"></div>
      </div>
    ';

  }

  // no matches, leave it as it is
  return $matches[0];
}

function my_content_filter($content){
  return
    preg_replace_callback('#\<a(.+?)\>(.+?)\<\/a\>#s', 'do_the_replacements', $content);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'my_content_filter');
```

Comment: I would definitely opt for this tactic. Saving all that HTML in your DB and loading it in the editor is a mess, and asking for trouble!

Comment: Thanks this looks much cleaner so far... do I put this in my functions file?  or the template file itself...

Comment: I tried adding to functions file, nothing happened.  Added to my page template file and get the following error:  *
Warning: preg_replace_callback() [function.preg-replace-callback]: Requires argument 2, 'do_the_replacements', to be a valid callback*

Comment: --- I think maybe it's because I have a lightbox plugin that auto-adds *rel="colorbox"* to the a tag...?

Comment: I dont think so... try adding the updated code in your functions file

Comment: Well that doesn't seem to do anything either?  I tried replacing 'someclass' with my lightbox class (cboxElement) but that didn't work.  I tried removing all links to the images in the edit page, and then replacing them, but that didn't work.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using `the_content()` to print that html to the screen?

Comment: Yes... and it's a real simple basic template so far.  The code doesn't have any advanced loops or anything.

Comment: Still haven't been able to fix this.

Comment: Post the html output seen by the browser, containing that link

Comment: http://pastebin.com/uLG8rTTf

Comment: ok, and did you replace `someclass` with `wp-image-` ?

Comment: Yes.  I tried *wp-image-* and *wp-image* and *cboxElement* and *colorbox* and none of those worked.

Comment: That's weird... it seems to work [here](http://codepad.org/an1tJpPD). Check if the content filter is being applied, by printing something in that function that you should see on the page.

Comment: Very interesting......  Well my time is pretty much up on this project.  I need to do something else before the client flips, so I think I'll just stick with some simple borders/shadows.  I'll give you the bounty since you helped me the most and its obviously working on you're code.  I know I must be doing something wrong somewhere! :)  Thanks for your help!